# Get a value from FB.api with a callback?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, callback, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have one simple question, been searching on Stack Overflow there are some questions on this topic but can't get a working solution.

I have a simple function for getting number of page likes on Javascript SDK:

```
function getLikes(div, graf) {
    var numblike;
    FB.api(graf, function(response) {
        var numblike = response.likes;
        $(div).prepend(numblike);
    });
    return numblike; // can't get it to return
}

var pLike = getLikes ("#mydiv", /app_id); // always undefined
```

Function works and it pre-pends the right number to my div but return always sets my variable to undefined. I understand that the script runs asynchronous and I need to use a callback function but I just can't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [javascript event loop](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/understanding-the-event-loops-and-writing-great-code-for-node-js-part-1/). you can't return numblike from the function cause it's set only in the callback of FB.api.
So you can do similar to that - just send callback:

```
function getLikes(div, graf,callback) {
  FB.api(graf, function(response) {
    var numblike = response.likes;
    $(div).prepend(numblike);
    callback(numblike);
  });

}

getLikes ("#mydiv", /app_id,function(numblike){
  alert(numblike);
}); // always undefined
```

Comment: alert inside the function worked before too. The goal here is to call this function and get page likes in a global variable, array to be more exact. So I can get page likes from a couple of different fb pages, store them in an array and then sum them altogether. so I would need `var pLikes = getLikes(etc...)` to return me a number I can then globaly use... In your case I get the alert but var still undefined.

Comment: Well. this is just an example how you can control your variant jeezes.
The point here is you can get access to numblike from facebook only via callback. so you can set var arr = []; above and inside the callback instead alert(numblike) you can do arr.push(numblike); . use your programming skills a bit...

Comment: Thank you for your input on this but I wasn't able to get it work the way I wanted. Switched to FB PHP SDK and solved the problem in the matter of minutes...

Answer (score 0):

You have decalred `numblike` two times, just remove var declaration in the second one:

```
function getLikes(div, graf) {
  var numblike;
  FB.api(graf, function(response) {
    numblike = response.likes; // var removed
    $(div).prepend(numblike);
  });
 return numblike; 
}
```